# Reputation page looks strange with accepted answers + downvotes

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I got an upvote, a downvote and an accept for the answer. The rep page shows:

[image]
https://stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception?tab=reputation#page_1-view_post

Doesn't that look a little odd? This is what it looks like when the post is not an accepted one:

[image]

Comment: +1 Good catch. I think it should say -2 as well. But it seems the downvote was removed since you posted; I can't see it in your profile anymore. There's another one on Aug 28th for [What is the difference between semicolons in JavaScript and in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219541/what-is-the-difference-between-semicolons-in-javascript-and-in-python/7219549#7219549) that still shows this behavior.

Comment: Why does an accept count as an 'upvote'?

Comment: @takrl Yes, the downvote was removed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep, display bug here, it will correctly be shown as a simple "-2" after the next build.

Comment: Has this been pushed out yet? Because I am still getting the bugged display.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ - can you give me a link to an example?

Comment: Check [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception?tab=reputation#page_1-view_post) on Aug 28th

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ - ummmm yeah, I can't really explain what happened to that changeset, it *will* actually go out tonight.

Comment: It is working now